# Transit Visa for England

Tags: visas, uk, visas-on-arrival, transit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UK Transit Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/uk-transit-visa)

I'm traveling to India From NYC via London, and my flight connecting time is 12 hours.
Can i get visa on arrival for England?