# Transit through London for US to India roundtrip

Tags: transit, london

I have US L1 visa on passport that expires in Jan2014. I am planning to visit India in Jan2014-Feb2014. I have my US H1 visa for which I will go to stamping in India. Now, can I travel through London? The visa I have on passport is for L1 that expires in Jan2014, but my return date is in Feb2014 and I will be coming back on H1. I will be transiting through London between 6th Jan 2014 to 12th Jan 2014.

I read few other similar questions but unable to judge whether to have valid US visa for return date or while passing through london.

Comment: See [Do I need a UK Transit Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/do-i-need-a-uk-transit-visa), or more specifically, the UK Border Agency page on [Do you need a visa to transit airside?](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-transit-airside/)?

Comment: You mention your visas and destinations but not your nationality, that could also be a factor.